# Find minimum value excluding 0 from a column range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need to find minimum value in a column range excluding 0.

Tried with this formula without success:

=MIN(IF((Data!H1:Data!H1711 <>0,Data!H1:Data!H1711))

[Excel file link.](https://techcosec-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/digitalsplendid_techcosec_onmicrosoft_com/EdQ810uIsEhPnTdicPMVdV8B1mGdIO3GiFl_SEE5aFz51w?e=6oDzPT)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2019 or newer

```
=MINIFS(H1:H1711,H1:H1711,"<> 0")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first or second `(` after the IF and it should work:

```
=MIN(IF(Data!H1:Data!H1711 <>0,Data!H1:Data!H1711))
```

You can also try the following formula to obtain the same result:

```
=SMALL(Data!H1:Data!H1711,COUNTIF(Data!H1:Data!H1711,0)+1)
```